# Android Studio with Kotlin How Does Control Pass From MainActivity to Another Class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using `android studio 4.1.1` and kotlin.

I'm trying to learn programming Android apps using Android Studio and Kotlin.  I have a question that a couple of tutorials and searching threads have not answered for me.   How does control pass from the `MainActivity.kt` class to another class, i.e: `FirstFragment.kt`?

I'm doing fine with other things I'm learning in tutorials, but I cannot figure this out.

Example:

I create a new Basic Activity app in Android Studio with Kotlin.  In the java directory, I see these classes:  FirstFragment.kt, MainActivity.kt and SecondFragment.kt.

In the res/layout/ directory, I see:  `activity_main.xml`, `content_main.xml`, `fragment_first.xml` and `fragment_second.xml`.

Question 1)  When the app loads in an emulator, I see the button and textView from the `fragment_first.xml`.  How does this happen?  I cannot see in the code where it says, "load fragment_first.xml".

`MainActivity.kt` has `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` which loads that layout.  activity_main.xml has `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`.  But from there, I do not know where to find the code that loads the `fragment_first.xml` layout.

I believe that when `fragment_first.xml` loads, control passes from `MainActivity.kt` to `FirstFragment.kt`, yes?  Question 2). Is this because of the onCreate function?

Thanks for helping me to understand this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to load a fragment. Traditionally, you use the FragmentManager to create a Fragment transaction that tells the Activity to place a Fragment into the view hierarchy and start managing its lifecycle.

More recently, they have added the Navigation component, which can be used in place of directly using the FragmentManager.

In the current new project Basic Activity, the layout `activity_main.xml` includes the layout `content_main`. In `content_main.xml`, you'll see that it includes a `fragment` element that is set to the Fragment (using the `name` parameter) `NavHostFragment`, which is a special Fragment that the Navigation component uses to host children fragments that are specified in a navigation XML file. This `fragment` element also specifies the navigation xml file using the `navGraph` property. It specifies `nav_graph.xml`, which you'll find in the `res/navigation` directory.

If you open `nav_graph.xml`, you'll see that it has `FirstFragment` set as the home fragment, so that is what pulls it up as the first fragment that you see.

Basically, the control flow is:

1. Activity's `onCreate()` sets content view to `activity_main`, which includes `content_main`.
2. `content_main` includes a NavHostFragment that is automatically inserted in the view hierarchy so the Activity starts running it.
3. The NavHostFragment is set in the XML to use `nav_graph`, which tells it to load FirstFragment first.

Comment: #Tenfour04 The light-bulb just went on!  Thank you so much for explaining that.  Makes perfect sense and clears up a couple other questions also.  Very Much Appreciated.